# "Array Dimension Missing, expected ' ; ' "

Tags: java, arrays, object, private

I'm trying pass customer data into a table. However, I keep getting the error message above when writing this private method. I'm fairly new to Java. Any help?

```
private void addCustomerToTable(Customer customer){
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) accountTable.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(model.getRowCount()+1);
    model.addRow(new Object[] (customer.getFirstName(), 
    customer.getLastName(), customer.getAccount().getAccountNumber(),
    customer.getAccount().getBalance()));

}
```

Comment: `new Object[] {customer.getFirstName(), 
    customer.getLastName(), customer.getAccount().getAccountNumber(),
    customer.getAccount().getBalance()}`

Comment: Note in @Eran's comment the use of braces rather than parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array Objects need to be defined/enclosed in curly-braces `{}` and not parenthesis `()`.

For example:

```
new Object[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

So in your case the code should be:

```
private void addCustomerToTable(Customer customer) {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) accountTable.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(model.getRowCount() + 1);
    model.addRow(new Object[] {
        customer.getFirstName(),
            customer.getLastName(), customer.getAccount().getAccountNumber(),
            customer.getAccount().getBalance()
    });
}
```

To learn more about Arrays in Java, refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html

Comment: This helped. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

(I'll format the code properly in a moment. Eclipse is taking a long time to start. and i'll delete this line as well, soon)

When you are creating an array and immediately populating it, You need curly brackets.
For example, if I create an array of double and I want it to contain the values 1,2,3,4,5, I'd do it like this:

```
double[] array = new double[]{1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0};//Notice: I didn't specify the length of the array.
```

Now, for your specific case you'd need:

```
model.addRow(new Object[] {
         customer.getFirstName(),
         customer.getLastName(),
         customer.getAccount().getAccountNumber(), 
         customer.getAccount().getBalance()
         });
```

Java will create an array with a length equal to the number of values given (in your case 4).

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html):

Alternatively, you can use the shortcut syntax to create and initialize an array:

> ```
> int[] anArray = { 
>     100, 200, 300,
>     400, 500, 600, 
>     700, 800, 900, 1000 };
> ```
>
> Here the length of the array is determined by the number of values provided between braces and separated by
> commas.